# Using only relative path instead of full path

Tags: python, windows, relative-path

I'm a very new python user using python 2.6.2 and my question is simple.

I want to only have the relative path `"\file_name"` in an input file instead of the full path like `"c:\folder_a\folder_b\file_name"` but when I use the relevant path in my input files I get the error `"Windows Error [Error 2]: The system cannot find the file specified..."` otherwise my code works fine.

What do I need to do/change so the system can use the relative path?  It seems since I'm running the script from the same folder such as `"c:\folder_a\folder_b>python script_name"` in the command terminal the relevant path alone should work.

Comment: The relative path is `file_name`, not `\file_name`. That first slash made it an absolute file name in the root directory.

Comment: it should work then, what happens if you say `"file_name"` instead, without the preceeding `"\"`?

Comment: Interestingly enough, after removing the "\" or adding the ".\" as Steve Barnes suggested before the "file_name" it seems to work on the first file in my input file list but when it goes to the second file it gives me the same error.  Before it gave me the error on the first file.

Answer (score 1):

Just try '.\file_name' as your path

2 issues . = current directory, (.. is up one), and you need to escape the \ as \ if using windows file separators.

Comment: Okay interestingly enough, after removing the back slash or adding the ".\" before the "file_name" it seems to work on the first file in my input file list but when it goes to the second file it gives me the error.  What can this be attributed to? I didn't understand what you meant by "2 issues . = current directory, (.. is up one), and you need to escape the \ as \ if using windows file separators."

Comment: Okay I think I understood your second line now.  However, problem still persists.  Adding ".\" or removing "\" runs first input file but gives error when it gets to second file.